# Is there a "Highlight selected word" feature for Jupyter Notebook 7?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-extensions

I recently upgraded my Notebook to Notebook 7 (on a Windows machine with Python 3.11). I would like to have a "Highlight selected word" feature like [the one in](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) `jupyter-contrib-nbextensions`. I am not able to use the `jupyter-contrib-nbextensions` even it is installed, so my question is - Is there a "Highlight selected word" feature for Jupyter Notebook 7?

(I don't want to downgrade my Notebook version)